# Admob: No ads on WiFi

Tags: android, ads, admob

I have an app that is not showing ads (at least for me, even in different cities and then with different WIFI), but it always shows ads on mobile data.

All my users are having this problem? I tried with two phones with different android version (4.1 and 7.1) and both are not showing ads on WIFI.

One device is giving error code 2 and other device error code 0.